# keypoints match between using optical flow

Tags: match, sift, opticalflow, keypoint

I have two pictures

PlanA :
I detect SIFT key poitns in picture A
and using optical flow to find the corresponding points in picture B

Plan B:
but if i detect SIFT key points in picture B
and do the match thing between picture A and picture B

What the diffences between Plan A and Plan B
which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

Plan A is motion estimation of the extracted points. Many of the algorithm work by comparing the intensity values in the neighborhood. Lucas Kanade is one good method.

Plan B may not find all points that are in image A.

Plan B is better. Optical flow does not work with sift descriptors. The excellent way of describing a neighborhood is lost in Plan A.

In Plan B: Many of the keypoints in A will not be matched in B. But those matched will have much higher confidence than in A.
In Plan A: Approximate matches of the points in A will be found

If A and B are continuous frames from video its profitable to use Plan A as the illumination does not change much in continuous frames of video and also Plan B is high on runtime (computing descriptors takes time), else use Plan B.

Cheers,